# Proving set containment for arbitrary sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Question:

$ Prove\ that\ (A \cup B) - C\ is\ a\ subset\ of\ [A - (B \cup C)] \cup [B - (A \cap C)]$

My attempt:

Let $ x \in (A \cup B) - C \implies x \in A\cup B  \ and\ x\notin C \implies (x \in A \ or\ x\in B) \ and\ x\notin C \implies ( x \in \ A\ and \ x\notin C) \ or\ ( x \in B \ and\ x\notin C) $

Case 1:

$ x \in A \ and\ x\notin C$, which means $ x\notin B $. So, $ x\in A \ and\ x\notin B \ and\ x\notin C \implies x\in A - B\cup C$.

Case 2:

$ x\in B \ and\ x\notin C$, which means $ x\notin A$. So $ x\in B \ and\ x\notin C \ and\ x\notin A \implies B - A\cap C$

Comment: Using Venn diagrams will help a lot for 2-set cases.

Comment: Could you see if I did it correctly now?

Comment: @user1952500 A 3-set Venn diagram will help even more!:)

Comment: Heh @Bram28 I have left my eyes somewhere today :)

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel In case 1 you can't infer $x \not \in B$, and in case 2 you can't infer $x \not \in A$

Comment: I am not sure how to prove it from here

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel split case 1 into two subcases: 1a) $x \in B$ and 1b) $x \not \in B$. YOu did 1b) already, and for 1a) show that $x \in B-(A\cap C)$. SImilarly split 2 into 2a) $x \in A and 2b) $x \not \in A ... and I assume you can take it from there!

Answer (score 1):

$$[A-(B \cup C)] \cup [B-(A \cap C)]=$$

$$[A \cap (B \cup C)^C]\cup [B \cap (A \cap C)^C]=$$

$$[A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [B \cap (A^C \cup C^C)]=$$

$$[A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [B \cap A^C] \cup [B \cup C^C]=$$

$$[A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [B \cap A^C \cap C] \cup [B \cap A^C \cap C^C] \cup [B \cap C^C \cap A] \cup [B \cap C^C \cap A^C]=$$

$$ [A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C^C] \cup [A \cap B \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C^C]=$$

$$[A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C ^C] \cup [A \cap B \cap C^C]=$$

$$[A \cap B^C \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C^C] \cup [A \cap B \cap C^C]\cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]=$$

$$[((A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)) \cap C^C]\cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]=$$

$$[(A \cap B^C) \cup B) \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]=$$

$$[(A \cup B) \cap C^C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]=$$

$$[(A \cup B)-C]\cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]$$

And there you have it: $[(A \cup B)-C] \cup [A^C \cap B \cap C]=[A-(B \cup C]\cup [B-(A\cap C)]$, and therefore $(A \cup B)-C \subseteq [A- (B \cup C)] \cup [B- ( A \cap C)]$